# ASP.NET INSERT statement with dynamically given value

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to do INSERT INTO table values from which one of them is dynamical. As follows, I have written this in .cs:

```
 query = "SELECT " + outColumn + " FROM [Proizvodnja].[dbo].[v_time] WHERE textile LIKE '" + outTextile + "'";
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***.***.***.***, 1433; Initial Catalog=******;User ID=******;Password=******;");
        SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdrOrder = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdrOrder.Read())
        {
            tv_min_String = rdrOrder.GetValue(0).ToString();
            tv_min = double.Parse(tv_min_String);

        }
        rdrOrder.Close();
        cn.Close();
```

I checked the very first query, it is OK. Now, I want tv_min value use in next insert statemet, to insert in table:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="insertOrder_plan_SqlDataSource" runat="server"
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Production].[dbo].[order_plan] (...,[v_time]) VALUES (..., @tv_min)">
 ...
 <InsertParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="tv_min" DefaultValue="<%= tv_min %>/>" Type="Decimal"/>
 </InsertParameters>
```

When I enter what need apears error msg:

```
 An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
 Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Whatis wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try using Double.TryParse instead of Double.Parse. it is safer

```
 Double.TryParse(tv_minString, tv_min))
```

Comment: err. "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: it needs two parameters

Comment: The same error, in addition is comment: When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object. But it is NOT caused with Date.

Comment: did you try initializing tv_min before using it?

Comment: I see an extra character "/>" where you pass in the value.

Comment: <asp:Parameter Name="tv_min" DefaultValue="<%= tv_min %>/>" Type="Decimal"/>
 should be   <asp:Parameter Name="tv_min" DefaultValue="<%= tv_min %>" Type="Decimal"/>